# How do I retrieve Step from a PluginType item

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have this code :

```
foreach (PluginAssembly tempPluginAssembly in pluginAssemblyList)
            {
                if (!tempPluginAssembly.Name.StartsWith("Microsoft.Crm"))
                {
                    List<PluginType> pluginList;
                    pluginList = xrmContext.PluginTypeSet.Where(Plugin => Plugin.PluginAssemblyId.Id == tempPluginAssembly.Id).ToList();

                    foreach (PluginType plugin in pluginList)
                    {
                        if (plugin.IsWorkflowActivity == false)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(new string[] { tempPluginAssembly.Name, tempPluginAssembly.Description, plugin.Name, String.Empty });
                            ++pluginCount;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Basically what it does is retrieve the assemblylist from my crm environment and filter the microsoft assemblies. Then, I retrieve every PluginType object contained in those assemblies and I log the information somewhere. But this isn't enough, I want to retrieve the steps that are contained in each of the PluginType objects.

How can I manage that? Is there a class I don't know about or an Attribute in the PluginType objects that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the `SdkMessageProcessingStep` entity to retrieve plugin steps. You can see the join in the query in the code below.

```
foreach (PluginAssembly tempPluginAssembly in pluginAssemblyList)
{
    if (!tempPluginAssembly.Name.StartsWith("Microsoft.Crm"))
    {
        var pluginList = from plugins in xrmContext.PluginTypeSet
                         join steps in xrmContext.SdkMessageProcessingStepSet on plugins.PluginTypeId equals steps.PluginTypeId.Id
                         where plugins.PluginAssemblyId.Id == tempPluginAssembly.Id
                         select new
                         {
                             plugins,
                             steps
                         };


        //_XrmContext.PluginTypeSet.Where(Plugin => Plugin.PluginAssemblyId.Id == tempPluginAssembly.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var plugin_step in pluginList)
        {
            if (plugin_step.plugins.IsWorkflowActivity == false)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(new string[] { tempPluginAssembly.Name, tempPluginAssembly.Description, plugin_step.plugins.Name, String.Empty });
                ++pluginCount;
            }
        }
    }
}
```